# How can I block traffic between two specific VLANs

Tags: networking, routing, vlan, access-control-list, dell-powerconnect

I have a Dell 6224 powerconenct switch acting as the core switch on our network. I have a number of VLANs configured, and the time has come for us to now consider blocking traffic between specific VLANs.

I currently use VLANs 2 - 10 and their respective subnets are 10.58.*v*.0/24 (where *v* is the VLAN ID). The router interface on each VLAN is 10.58.*v*.1

For example VLAN 5 uses 10.58.5.0/24, with a gateway of 10.58.5.1

What I want to do, is to block all IP traffic between VLAN 5 and VLAN 8, i.e. anything with an IP in the range of 10.58.5.0/24 can't communicate with anything in 10.58.8.0/24 and vice versa.

As this is a production network (and I don't have a test environment available), I don't want to just start creating ACLs, in case I mess up.

My first thought was to create an access list such as..

```
access-list testacl deny ip 10.58.5.0 255.255.255.0 10.58.8.0 255.255.255.0
```

But I don't really know if this needs to be assigned to a specific interface?

Update:

I've been reading further and realise that I now need to add a permit rule, for everything else, otherwise the implied deny all rule will block everything, so my testacl now looks like this:

```
access-list testacl deny ip 10.58.5.0 255.255.255.0 10.58.8.0 255.255.255.0
access-list testacl permit every
```

But I'm still unsure if this is correct, and would appreciate any assistance, as I don't want to risk reconfiguring production switches without fully understanding other possible side effects of what I'm doing.

Comment: What does the existing routing table look like on the switch?

Comment: routing is enabled on all interfaces (except the management VLAN), and a default route exists for 0.0.0.0/0 to our internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions, but as I've now resolved this, this might help someone else.

Firstly, the netmask above is incorrect, I should have used a [Wild Card Mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_mask)

After some research I found that the correct commands to create the ACL were:

```
access-list testacl deny ip 10.58.5.0 0.0.0.255 10.58.8.0 0.0.0.255
access-list testacl permit every
```

...and to apply the ACL, I used the following:

```
interface vlan 5
ip access-group testacl
```

After the research I did, I felt confident to apply the ACL to the production switches, and the change worked flawlessly.